# How to disable .htaccess file using JavaScript?

Tags: htaccess, javascript, security

By the way, the  `.htaccess` was already enabled to my main directory. Is there any way to disable it using `JavaScript`? to my client-side? I was just curious about how my `files` are being secured. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. There isn't a way for a very good reason.

The htaccess file cannot and should not ever be modified by the client. If it were possible to implement a workaround to that, you would have just created the mother of all security flaws on your server.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate that. Now I know how secured it is. :P